# xjc generating wrong List<String> for @XMLAttribute

Tags: java, xsd, xjc

I have an [XML Schema](https://github.com/adamretter/exist-algolia-index/blob/master/src/main/resources/xsd/exist-algolia-index-config.xsd) which defines an XML element called "attribute" with an XML attribute called "path" which when given to `xjc 2.2.8-b130911.1802` seems to generate the wrong Java code.

Java generated code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "attribute")
public class Attribute {

  @XmlAttribute(name = "path", required = true)
  protected List<String> path;
}
```

Relevant Schema parts:

```
  <xs:element name="attribute">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="c:absoluteElementPathOrAbsoluteOrRelativeAttributePathWithPredicate"/
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="absoluteElementPathOrAbsoluteOrRelativeAttributePathWithPredicate">
    <xs:attribute name="path" use="required" type="c:absoluteElementPathOrAbsoluteOrRelativeAttributePathWithPredicateType"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:simpleType name="absoluteElementPathOrAbsoluteOrRelativeAttributePathWithPredicateType">
    <xs:union memberTypes="c:absoluteElementPathWithPredicateType c:absoluteOrRelativeAttributePathWithPredicateType"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="absoluteElementPathWithPredicateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="/|(//?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?(\[@[0-9a-zA-Z]+(:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?\s*(eq|ne|=)\s*'[^']*'\])?)+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="absoluteOrRelativeAttributePathWithPredicateType">
    <xs:union memberTypes="c:absoluteAttributePathWithPredicateType c:relativeAttributeNameType"/>
  </xs:simpleType>


  <xs:simpleType name="absoluteAttributePathWithPredicateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="/|(//?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?(\[@[0-9a-zA-Z]+(:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?\s*(eq|ne|=)\s*'[^']*'\])?)+\/@[0-9a-zA-Z]+(:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="relativeAttributeNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="@[0-9a-zA-Z]+(:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

As far as I am aware, it is impossible to have more than one XML attribute of the same name on the same XML element, therefore any generated `@XMLAttribute` Java code should always be a `String` and not a `List<String>`.

Can someone please confirm that I seem to have hit a bug in XJC?
Also does anyone know where to report bugs in XJC?

Comment: Hi Adam, schema aside, `protected List<String> path;` in itself seems fine and in my understanding (as explained on https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1.3/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html ) is mapped to one single attribute that has a type that is a list (in the XML Schema sense) of space-separated strings. However, indeed, I see no list in the schema so that I'd expect a field of type String, like you. Maybe something is going on in xjc's implementation of union types?

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding Ghislain. I will try and figure out where I should open an issue for this...